# Recuparar imagem e retornar pra funçao

Tags: php

Eu preciso passar um arquivo de imagem para uma determinada funçao, essa funçao normalmente recebe a imagem de um upload assim:

```
$filter = new ImageFilter;
$score = $filter->GetScore($_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name']);
```

porém preciso passar uma imagem já existente no servidor para esta funçao, como fazer?

Comment: Teoricamente, a imagem existe no servidor, porém é temporária, até que o PHP termine de executar. Você quer salvá-la em um outro lugar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código que tens atualmente, está a fazer uso de um ficheiro temporário que acabou de ser enviado para o servidor:

```
$filter = new ImageFilter;
$score = $filter->GetScore($_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name']);
```

Para utilizares um ficheiro que já existe, basta forneceres o caminho e nome do mesmo:

```
$caminho = "/caminho/completo/para/a/minha/imagem/";
$imagem = "nomeDaImage.jpg";

$filter = new ImageFilter;
$score = $filter->GetScore($caminho.$imagem);
```

---

## Elaboração

O código na pergunta vem de uma classe escrita em PHP que apura o *score* de determinada imagem para efeitos de prevenção de upload de imagens "para adultos" ou contendo "nudismo".

A [classe](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3269-PHP-Determine-whether-an-image-may-contain-nudity.html) é oriunda do site [phpclasses.org](http://www.phpclasses.org/), site cortesia do nosso estimado [@mlemos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2942/mlemos), tendo sido desenvolvida e publicada por Bakr Alsharif:

## [*Image Nudity Filter*: Determinar se uma imagem pode conter nudez](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3269-PHP-Determine-whether-an-image-may-contain-nudity.html)

Podemos observar no método utilizado `GetScore` que o mesmo invoca o método `_GetImageResource` passando-lhe o argumento sem alterações:

```
function GetScore($image)
{
    $x = 0; $y = 0;
    $img = $this->_GetImageResource($image, $x, $y);

    // ...
}
```

Já no método `_GetImageResource`, o mesmo passa o argumento, novamente sem alterações, para várias funções de PHP, todas elas esperando receber um caminho para um ficheiro existente:

```
function _GetImageResource($image, &$x, &$y)
{
    $info = GetImageSize($image);
    
    $x = $info[0];
    $y = $info[1];
    
    switch( $info[2] )
    {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            return @ImageCreateFromGif($image);
            
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            return @ImageCreateFromJpeg($image);
            
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            return @ImageCreateFromPng($image);
            
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Ver documentação para [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php), [`imagecreatefromgif()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php), [`imagecreatefromjpeg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) e [`imagecreatefrompng()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php).

Answer (score 1):

Você quer passar em uma função a informação de uma imagen já alocada em sua pasta, no servidor, ou seja, após o upload.

**Você pode checar:** [readdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)

E assim obter a lista de suas imagens:

```
<?php

    if ($handle = opendir('.')) {

    while (false !== ($entry[] = readdir($handle))) {  }
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {

          echo '<pre>';
          print_r($entry);
          echo '</pre>';


        }


    closedir($handle);
}

?>
```

---

### RESULTADO:

```
Array
(
    [0] => imagem1.jpg
    [1] => imagem2.jpg
    [2] => imagem3.jpg
)
```

*obs:* *Esse código lista os arquivos no qual ele está alocado. Mude o valor de `opendir('CAMINHO/CAMINHO')`, para acessar outras pastas.*

Então com o valor de $entry, em array, você passa uma verificação para encontrar a imagem que quer:

```
<?php

    if (in_array("imagem1.jpg", $entry)) { 

        $parametro = 'imagem1.jpg';

    }else{

      $parametro = 'ARQUIVO NÃO ENCONTRADO';

    }

    echo $parametro;

?>
```

Por fim passa na função:

```
$filter = new ImageFilter;
$score = $filter->GetScore($parametro);
```